# jquery function not working in Safari?

Tags: jquery, safari, attributes

Is there something unique about Safari that would render the code below useless?  While it works as expected in all the other browsers, it fails in Safari, insomuch that the attribute isn't removed at all...

```
$('ul.nice-menu a').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
});
```

Comment: What version of jquery are you using? It might be a jQuery bug, as it looks like removeAttr calls removeAttribute on the underlying DOM element, although there are inconsistencies across browsers, which is why the method exists.

Comment: Is there any error message displayed in the Web Inspector Console tab? What version of jQuery do you use? Is it the latest version?

Comment: It's v1.2.6.  It's part of the Drupal CMS though, so it wouldn't surprise me that something somewhere is mucking things up.  I was hoping that someone would say, "Yes, there is something incredibly wrong with what you've done", but guess not?

Comment: also, Web Inspector doesn't show anything odd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for an `each` loop. Try the following:

```
$('ul.nice-menu a').removeAttr("title");
```

I'm not sure that will fix it though.

Comment: I just tested `removeAttr` on anchors with titles on safari, seems fine (jQuery 1.4.1). Is your $(document).ready?

Comment: Can you upgrade the jQuery 1.4.1, see if the bug still exist. Also, do you use the latest Safari?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real response, but have you tried

```
$(this).attr('title','');
```

?

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I'm trying to avoid... It outputs a blank title, which is causing problems.